# Am I on the right track with my singleton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, singleton, nstimer

I asked a question yesterday regarding my table view and linking unique detail views to each cell in the table view. I believe I got a good answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905263/2533646). (Hopefully you can read that post and see what I need). Basically I wanted to know if I am making my singleton correctly. Here is my code:

**timerStore.h**

```
#import "Tasks.h"
@interface timerStore : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *allItems;
}
+(timerStore *)sharedStore;
-(NSDictionary *)allItems;
-(NSTimer *)createTimerFor:(Tasks *)t inLocation: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)timerAction;
@end
```

**timerStore.m**

```
@implementation timerStore

+(timerStore *)sharedStore{
    static timerStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore)
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];
    return sharedStore;
}
+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return [self sharedStore];
}
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        allItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSDictionary *)allItems{
    return allItems;
}
-(NSTimer *)createTimerFor:(Tasks *)t inLocation: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:t.timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:1.0];
    [allItems setObject:timer forKey:indexPath];
    return timer;
}
-(void)timerAction{
//custom properties here
}
@end
```

I'm kind of confused because I was under the impression that a cell's index path gets recycled as you scroll down (dequeue). I may be wrong though. Anyway, am I on the right path to making a singleton as the guy in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905263/2533646) suggested?

Comment: You know, I've been programming iOS for 4 years now -- worked on a half-dozen different large apps.  I've yet to need to use a singleton.

Comment: In particular, if you have a table view you must have a view controller for it.  That view controller can contain the data for the table (functioning as a delegate).  There is no need for a singleton to store table data.

Comment: yea i wanted to avoid using singletons but i didn't know how else to do this. basically im using the NSFetchedResultsController to populate the table view (linked to UIViewController subclass). Each cell should have a timer in its detail view (which results from didSelectRowAtIndexPath). Apparently a singleton is the best way to make sure multiple timers can co-exist and reduce memory usage by limiting the detail view to one intialization...more info is at the link in the OP

Comment: Not related to question but "Never ever start class names with lower case !!!"

Comment: It's not clear to me that using a singleton is the way to go. Even though the answer I gave to your other question involves creating a new detail view controller for each row selected, that's not necessarily a bad thing. When profiling that app with instruments, selecting nine rows only added 1.8 kb of memory -- view controllers are not that heavy an object (but that might depend on what you have in them, especially images). How many tasks do you think a user would be creating?  A few? Tens? Hundreds?

Comment: Honestly probably 20 at most

Comment: By the way, like I said before, I was under the impression that a cell's index path gets recycled as you scroll down (dequeue). Doesn't that mean marking each cell with a number identifier would result in multiple cells for the same identifier?

Comment: Also, if you stored each view controller with a indexPath key, how do you make sure the key isn't set to two view controllers..? For example. Let's say you have 4 cells, which means 4 view controllers. You delete cell 3. Cell 4 moves down to cell 3s spot. You create a new cell which goes to spot 4. Now you have two controllers with the same indexPath key! How do you avoid this??

Comment: You maintain an NSMutableArray that "shadows" the contents of the table.

Comment: You keep saying "the cell's index path gets recycled". The index path doesn't get recycled; the cell is what gets recycled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to implement App Singleton is as follows

**Header file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppSingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username;

+ (AppSingleton *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

**Implementation File**

```
#import "AppSingleton.h"

@implementation AppSingleton
@synthesize username;

+ (AppSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static AppSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

// Initializing
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        username = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Note:**
What this does is it defines a static variable (but only global to this [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)) called `sharedInstance` which is then **initialised once and only once** in `sharedInstance` Method. The way we ensure that it’s only created once is by using the `dispatch_once method` from [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). This is thread safe and handled entirely by the OS for you so that you don’t have to worry about it at all.

**Using Singleton To set value**

```
[[AppSingleton sharedInstance] setUsername:@"codebuster"];
```

**Using Singleton to get value.**

```
NSString *username = [[AppSingleton sharedInstance] username];
```

[**Further Reference and Reading**](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

Comment: Why don't you refer the OP to [this page](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) instead? By the way did you *read* the question at all?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I used to refer to links but mostly get downvoted for that. :)

Comment: thanks for telling me how to make a singleton, but i was more interested if i was on the right track in the context of what the guy in the link (in original post) suggested

Comment: I think it can not prevent user to use `[[AppSingleton alloc] init]` get another instance in ARC. And I have a look at your link , in NON-ARC , it can prevent user to use `[[AppSingleton alloc] init]` get another instance.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen It is better to have an answer **written** than a link to some other place

Comment: @KhanhNguyen: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc/7569010#7569010 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat/9119089#9119089 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c or....  Just do a search here on SO and mark this as a duplicate if that's all that you want to add...

Comment: My question has not been answered... i was more interested if i was on the right track in the context of what the guy in the link (in original post) suggested